# Test class for batch apex that sends out email

Tags: email

Below is the snippet of the batch class that sends out email.

```
 global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC)
        {
            query = 'Select id , user__c from object1';
            return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
        }
        global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<object1> scope)
        {
            List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>  myEmails = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
            Id templateId =  [select id, name from EmailTemplate where developername = 'template1'].id;

            for(object1 s:scope)
            {

                        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();  
                        if(templateId != null )
                        {
                            email.setTemplateId(templateId);
                            email.setTargetObjectId(s.User__c);
                            email.setwhatid(s.id);
                            email.setSaveAsActivity(false);
                            myEmails.add(email); 
                        }             
                   }
                }   
            }
            If(!myEmails.IsEmpty()) 
            {
                    try 
                    {                   
                        Messaging.sendEmail(myEmails);
                    }
                    catch(Exception ex) {
                        System.debug('exception : '+ex.getmessage());
                    }
            }        
        }
        global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC)
        {

        }
```

I have written a test class for the above class. I am however unable to figure out how to add assert statements in the test class. I googled and came across Limits.getEmailInvocations(). In the test class there is only one record and hence only one email can be sent. Hence i tried putting System.assertEquals(1, Limits.getEmailInvocations()), but the assert failed saying the actual value is 0 not 1.

Comment: Emails are not sent from the test class. I believe that is the reason your assertion is failing.

Comment: as an aside - you are constrained by the # of emails you can send per day via apex and should use the reserveEmailCapacity() method with suitable exception handler to deal with retries on subsequent days

Answer (score 1):

This works for me (with my utility send email class at V36):

```
@isTest
private static void testEmail() {


    //  Verify email sent when valid parms
    Integer emailsSentBefore    = Limits.getEmailInvocations();
    try {
        new Util.Email()
            .withToAddrs(new List<String>{'foo@bar.com'})
            .withPlainTextBody('fooBody')
            .sendEmail();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {System.assert(false,'shouldnt happen, valid email: ' + e.getMessage());}
    System.assert(Limits.getEmailInvocations() > emailsSentBefore,'if email successfully queued, then invocations should be more than when we started');
}
```